# kendo pivot grid custom dynamic measures

Tags: dynamic, kendo-grid, pivot-table, measure

Is there any way to create measures with custom conditions, that users needed,
dynamically In kendo pivot table.

I found there is an option to create custom measures like,

```
 measures: {
    "ChainShare": {
        field: "ChainShare",
        aggregate: "sum"
    }, 
    "DemandIndex": {
       field: "DemandIndex",
        aggregate: function (value, state, context) { 
         var dataItem = context.dataItem;
                var ChainShare = dataItem.ChainShare;
                var GroupShare = dataItem.GroupShare;

                // manual aggregation
               state.ChainShare = ( state.ChainShare || 0 ) + ChainShare;
               state.GroupShare = ( state.GroupShare || 0 ) + GroupShare;
           },
          result: function(state){
                if ( state.ChainShare == 0 || state.GroupShare == 0 ){
                   return 0;
                } else {
                    return (state.ChainShare / state.GroupShare) ;
             }
            }
         },    "GroupShare": {
        field: "GroupShare",
       aggregate: "sum"
    }
}
```

But this aggregate function is static that user cant add more condition to it.

*Simply, I need to create measures from front end dynamically.*